# Item Type HTTP Agent not parsing Json Response

Tags: zabbix

I have a C# application that return a Json status when I call "http://host:port/app-status".

The response looks like:

```
{
  "prtg": 
  {
    "result": [
      {
        "channel": "DDS - ZDM - Konsistenzprüfung",
        "value": "3",
        "valuelookup": "prtg.RCLookup.DDS_ZDM_Check.BitField"
      },
      {
        "channel": "ZDM DB Verbindungsversuche",
        "value": "0",
        "valuelookup": "prtg.RCLookup.Default.DB.Connect.Retry"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Then i have on zabbix server an item which type is http agent. 
The request works fine. But I get this error:

> Preprocessing failed for: HTTP/1.1 200 Ok..Content-Length: 361..Content-Type: application/json..Server: Grapevine/4.1.1.0 M...
>   1. Failed: cannot extract value from json by path ".prtg.result[0].value": cannot parse as a valid JSON object: invalid object format, expected opening character '{' or '[' at: 'HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
>   Content-Length: 361
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   Server: Grapevine/4.1.1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
>   Date: Fri, 12 Apr 2019 14:19:12

In the preprocessing tab I have set a processing step with JsonPath.
The JsonPath is: .prtg.result[0].value

What is wrong?
Can help me everybody?

Answer (score 0):

from error message it seems that you are trying to parse response from server inclusive headers which is wrong - you need to parse as JSON only data which is sent back (exclusive headers)